# Create image from data placed in table (PHP)

Tags: php, image.createimage

I want to create an image from the data I placed in a table.

My code so far:

```
$out = "<table><tr><td>There will be data</td></tr></table>";
header('Content-type: image/png');
$png_image = imagecreate(50, 500);
$tcol = imagecolorallocate($png_image, 255, 255, 0);
imagestring($png_image, 4, 30, 25, $out, $tcol);
//echo $out;
imagepng($png_image);
imagedestroy($png_image);
```

But I got this as output:

> �PNG  IHDR2�E7��PLTE�����E pHYs���+IDATH���1 �Om����*�IEND�B`�

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You have to use the data inside the `<table>` tag or you have use the whole `$out` variable?

Comment: I want to use the whole `$out` variable

Comment: To display an image you will need some `<img>` tag in your HTML code...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code is working fine. I got this as output:

[image: OUTPUT]